# scoped_ptr to call member function throws error

Tags: c++, boost, scoped-ptr

I am currently reading Accelerated C++ ch13 and thought of doing sample program given in book via boost scoped_ptr but have encountered an error.
 May you guys please bail me out.

**

```
***error: cannot use arrow operator on a type
      record->read( cin );***
            ^
```

**

***Original sample code is something shown below and this works flawlessly***

```
std::vector< Core* > students ; // read students
    Core* records;
    std::string::size_type maxlen = 0;
    // read data and store in an object
    char ch ;

        while( cin >> ch )
        {
            if( 'U' == ch )
            {
                records = new Core;

            }
            else if( 'G' == ch )
            {
            records = new Grad;
            }

         records->read( cin );

        maxlen = max( maxlen , records->getname().size() );
        students.push_back( records );
    }
```

***Now using scoped_ptr MY VERSION***

```
typedef boost::scoped_ptr<Core> record;
    std::vector< record > students;
    char ch;
    std::string::size_type maxlen = 0;
    // read and store
    while( ( cin >> ch )   )
    {
        if( ch == 'U')
        {
            record( new Core);
        }
        else if( ch == 'G')
        {        
             record( new Grad);
        }

       record->read( cin );// GOT ERROR
       //maxlen = max( maxlen, record->name().size() );// SAME type of  error I EXPECT HERE
      // students.push_back( record );

    }
```

Comment: `record` is a type, not a variable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Thanks mate , but when i use boost::scoped_ptr<Core> record without typedef it throws different error. So what is the corrrect way to solve it

Comment: `boost::scoped_ptr<Core> record; if (ch == 'U') record.reset(new Core); else record.reset(new Grad); record->read(cin);`

Comment: I did what you said.  in addition   std::vector< boost::scoped_ptr<Core> > students;// is there better way to do this line?                                                      Also students.push_back( record ); throws error ->/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/new_allocator.h:107: error: calling a private constructor of class 'boost::scoped_ptr<Core>'
      { ::new(__p) _Tp(__val); }

Comment: I'm pretty sure `boost::scoped_ptr` can't be stored in a `vector` - it's not copyable and not movable. Use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, Thanks mate , I will try that and let you know how i did. Thanks again for prompt help